# Find modified project file by Visual Studio (SSDT) that is not saved yet

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

We are facing situation when some developers modify the project file (*.sqlproj) for example by adding or removing objects, then they do not save all the files in the Visual Studio and try to commit/push changes using command line. In that case the *.sqlproj file is not saved yet and it is not caught by the git. There is no problems when you commit/push from Visual Studio as it warns you that you have not saved files and asks you what to do.

So the question... Is there a way to find that the file is modified, but not saved yet? Maybe there are some temp files location or any other proper way of doing that?